# Implementing Google Reviews for a Travel Company

Tags: php

I work for a large online travel company that allows customers to book hotels.

They currently show users Trip Advisor reviews of the property they are currently viewing but are wanting to switch to Google Reviews instead.

I believe the correct API is Google Places but it appears limited to 5 reviews? Is there any sort of widget or way to implement Google Reviews?

Just to note, this is not to show reviews of our business but of a hotel searched for by a user.

Comment: If you are unable to fetch more than 5 or get provisioned a GMB API key you can always use a third-party widget; eg: reviewsmaker.com

Answer (score 0):

1) first of all you need to white list your google my business api for whatever project you are working on in your project as its private api. Google my business api will work on the locations associated with your account so make sure you verified the LOCATIONS from any account you know. Then you can try out the api call you mentioned in OAuthplayground.

2) Follow steps mentioned in below documentation URL to set it up: 
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs
   After the setup and etc you will automatically understand the account id and location id.

i am providing the api that will help you to get the fetch the review

1. get account details:
   [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token={access_token}](http://%20%20%20%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)
2. get location Id
   [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountID}/locations?access_token={access_token}](http://%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountID%7D/locations?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)
3. get review 
   [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountID}/locations/{location_id}/reviews?access_token={access_token}](http://%20%20%20%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountID%7D/locations/%7Blocation_id%7D/reviews?access_token=)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

We allow booking of thousands of hotels and these properties don't belong to us so no ability to setup a location id.

We need to obtain reviews using lat and long.

Comment: @Narendra could you please tell me how to get access token? I use key, Service Account JSON file in my different APIs. but don't know about the token. Can you tell me where from I will get this access token?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 you can refer this link @HassanRaza